# Table Renderer not working correctly in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering, tablecellrenderer

I read a lot of articles and finally got my JTable rendering as per my requirements but the problem is when the table is scrolled by user, some of the other hidden parts of jtable are also colored as shown in image below

[image]

And when the user scrolls the table, other parts are also got colored like this

[image]

Why this happens? I read many articles and and all of them show exactly the same thing but this...

Here is my code

```
JTable table = new JTable()
{
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) 
    {
        return false;
    }
};

(DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer())
.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object [][] {}, Columns));
table.setRowHeight(25);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 
table.getColumnModel().removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if(!table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 10).toString().equals("true"))
        {
            setBackground(new Color(246,137,137));
        }
        return this;
    }
 });

 JScrollPane areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
 areaScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
 MyPanel.add(areaScrollPane);
```

All the articles show this way to render custom row on condition base. What's wrong in my code? Thanks for any support.

Comment: you are seting the background of this instead of the Component you are supposed to return. Component c=super. ... c.setBackground ... return c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(!table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 10).toString().equals("true"))
{
    setBackground(new Color(246,137,137));
}
```

The same renderer is used for all cells so once you set the background it will apply for all cells. So, I think you need something like:

```
if(!table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 10).toString().equals("true"))
{
    setBackground(new Color(246,137,137));
}
else
    setBackground( table.getBackground() );
```

You should also add code to make sure the cell is not selected so that the default selection color can be painted.

Instead of using a custom renderer you can also override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of JTable. [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) show how you can render a row based on a value in that row.

Comment: Man this took me the whole of my Day and you just suggested one thing which perfectly fitted. Wonderful. Excellent. Thanks alot. Man. Camickr only one thing that please can you tell me if there is anything else wrong in my way of coding? means is there anything I can make my code more better keeping in mind the requirements like **setDefaultRenderer** and **getTableHeader()** and **isCellEditable** etc

Comment: @JavaDrunk Java variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of the variables in your posted code are correct, but you have one variable "MyPanel" which is not correct. This is confusing and there is no reason to do this, so my general comment is `be consistent`.